# update programmatically added label based on textbox value

Tags: c#

I'm a new c# programmer and having trouble updated my programmatically added label based on the textbox value. It works fine if the textboxes and labels are added using the form designer but the quantity textboxes and labels will vary based on my user's data so I will be adding them using code. The label added in code is unfortunately not accessible in the Text_Changed event and my searches on the internet haven't made it clear how to accomplish this. Below is my code.

```
namespace Test_Form_Controls
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            TextBox txtBox1 = new TextBox();
            txtBox1.Text = "0";
            txtBox1.Location = new Point(100, 25);
            Controls.Add(txtBox1);
            txtBox1.TextChanged += txtBox1_TextChanged;
            Label label1 = new Label();
            label1.Text = "0";
            label1.Location = new Point(25, 25);
            Controls.Add(label1);
        }

        private void txtBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox objTextBox = (TextBox)sender;
            label1.Text = objTextBox.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your label only exists in the ctor because that is where it is declared.  You can find it (and any others) in the controls collection.

Comment: Move your label to be a private field.

Answer (score 0):

Move your label to be a private field

```
namespace Test_Form_Controls
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Label label1;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            TextBox txtBox1 = new TextBox();
            txtBox1.Text = "0";
            txtBox1.Location = new Point(100, 25);
            Controls.Add(txtBox1);
            txtBox1.TextChanged += txtBox1_TextChanged;
            label1 = new Label();
            label1.Text = "0";
            label1.Location = new Point(25, 25);
            Controls.Add(label1);
        }

        private void txtBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox objTextBox = (TextBox)sender;
            label1.Text = objTextBox.Text;
        }
    }
}
```